# Java Sockets. Hanging on ObjectInputStream()

Tags: java, sockets

I'm currently writing a P2P application with a paxos consensus algorithm using java sockets and have come across an issue where my program seems to hang on ObjectOutputStream().

Each member in the P2P network has a List for all outgoing connections, as well as a server thread to handle incoming connections. This server thread then has a serversocket, which spawns a handler thread for every incoming socket that is accepted.

Firstly, here is my Member class. The key functions here are `sendProposalToAll()` and `sendResponse()`.

```
/**
 * Represents a member in the P2P member network
 */
public class Member {

    private Integer portNumber;
    private String memberName;

    private List<Socket> clientSockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    private MemberServerThread serverThread;

    /**
     * Constructs the member with given portnumber
     * Spawns thread for the member and initialises all client sockets
     * 
     * @param memberName the name of the member
     * @param portNumber the port number for the member to use for it's client and
     *                   server sockets
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs when creating a client socket or
     *                     opening the server socket
     */
    public Member(String memberName, Integer portNumber) throws IOException {

        this.memberName = memberName;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;

        // initialise clients
        for (Integer port : MemberNetwork.getOtherMemberPorts(portNumber)) {
            clientSockets.add(new Socket("localhost", port));
        }

        // initialise server
        serverThread = new MemberServerThread(portNumber);
        serverThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new socket connection to the new member of the P2P network
     * 
     * @param newMemberPort the port of the new member added to the P2P network
     * @throws UnknownHostException if the IP address of the host could not be
     *                              determined
     * @throws IOException          if an I/O error occurs when creating the socket
     */
    private void addNewMember(Integer newMemberPort) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        clientSockets.add(new Socket("localhost", newMemberPort));
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the member name
     */
    public String getMemberName() {
        return memberName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the member port number
     */
    public Integer getPortNumber() {
        return portNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new socket connection to the new member of the P2P network
     * 
     * @param newMemberPort the port of the new member added to the P2P network
     * @throws UnknownHostException if the IP address of the host could not be
     *                              determined
     * @throws IOException          if an I/O error occurs when creating the socket
     */
    public void createNewClientSocket(Integer newMemberPort) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        addNewMember(newMemberPort);
    }

    /**
     * Invokes the client thread to send the proposal to all other members of the
     * P2P network
     * 
     * @param proposal the proposal to send to the other members on the P2P network
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs when creating the output stream or
     *                     if the socket is not connected or if an I/O error occurs
     *                     while writing stream header
     */
    public void sendProposalToAll(PropositionType type, String proposedMember) throws IOException {

        Proposal proposal = new Proposal(portNumber, type, proposedMember);

        for (Socket socket : clientSockets) {

            // create object output stream from the socket
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
            objectOutputStream.flush();

            // send the proposal
            System.out.println(
                    "Sending proposal to " + MemberNetwork.getMemberByPortNumber(socket.getPort()).getMemberName());
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(proposal);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Invokes the client thread to send the response to the desired member of the
     * P2P network
     * 
     * @param type       the type of response
     * @param proposalId the proposal Id that the response refers to
     * @param memberName the name of the member that the response is targetting
     * @throws IOException     if an I/O error occurs when creating the output
     *                         stream or if the socket is not connected or if an I/O
     *                         error occurs while writing stream header
     * @throws SocketException if the specified destination port does not match any
     *                         server socket
     */
    public void sendReponse(ResponseType type, int proposalId, String memberName) throws SocketException, IOException {

        Response response = new Response(type, proposalId, portNumber,
                MemberNetwork.getMemberByName(memberName).getPortNumber());

        // find socket with required destination port
        Socket socket = clientSockets
                .stream()
                .filter(
                        clientSocket -> response
                                .getDestinationPort()
                                .equals(clientSocket.getPort()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        if (socket == null) {
            throw new SocketException("Server socket on port: " + response.getDestinationPort() + "does not exist");
        }

        // create object output stream from the socket
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        outputStream.flush();

        // send the proposal
        System.out.println(
                "Sending response to " + MemberNetwork.getMemberByPortNumber(socket.getPort()).getMemberName());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(response);
    }
}
```

Next is the server thread shown below, which simply spawns the handlers

```
/**
 * The Member's Server Thread
 * Responsible for handling the member's server socket and connected clients
 */
public class MemberServerThread extends Thread {
    
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    /**
     * Initialises the member's server thread by creating
     * a server socket which listens on the given port number
     * 
     * @param portNumber the port number for the server to bind to
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs when opening the socket.
     */
    public MemberServerThread(Integer portNumber) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    }


    // run the thread
    public void run() {
        
        // connect to peers
        while (true) {
            try {
                new IncomingMemberHandler(serverSocket.accept()).start();
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the last relevant file is the following, which has had some things removed to showcase the problem.

```
/**
 * Handles the individual sockets connected to the member's server socket
 */
public class IncomingMemberHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket incomingMember;

    private Map<Integer, Integer> acceptedPromises = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    /**
     * Initialises a member handler
     * 
     * @param memberSocket the incoming member socket connected to the server
     */
    public IncomingMemberHandler(Socket memberSocket) {
        this.incomingMember = memberSocket;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            // create object input stream from the socket
            InputStream inputStream = incomingMember.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

            Object incomingObject = objectInputStream.readObject();

            // obtain the proposal
            if (incomingObject.getClass().equals(Proposal.class)) {

                Proposal incomingProposal = (Proposal) incomingObject;
                int proposalId = incomingProposal.getId();

                // get proposer port
                Integer proposerPort = incomingMember.getLocalPort();

                // get the proposer
                Member proposer = MemberNetwork.getMemberByPortNumber(proposerPort);
                String proposerName = proposer.getMemberName();

                // get the acceptor
                Member acceptor = MemberNetwork.getMemberByPortNumber(incomingProposal.getSourcePort());
                acceptor.sendReponse(ResponseType.PROMISE_ACCEPTED, proposalId, proposerName);

                System.out.println("Received " + incomingProposal.getType() + " from " + proposerName);

                // obtain the response
            } else if (incomingObject.getClass().equals(Response.class)) {

                Response incomingResponse = (Response) incomingObject;

                // get the acceptor
                Member acceptor = MemberNetwork.getMemberByPortNumber(incomingResponse.getSourcePort());
                String acceptorName = acceptor.getMemberName();

                acceptedPromises.merge(incomingResponse.getId(), 1, Integer::sum);

                System.out.println("Received " + incomingResponse.getType() + " from " + acceptorName);

            } else {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException("Unexpected Class: " + incomingObject.getClass());
            }

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Everything works as expected, except for when `sendResponse()` is hit in `IncomingMemberHandler`. I've tried debugging and have found that it does successfully run the `sendResponse()` function, however, once

```
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

is hit, the program hangs and never continues forward.

I was hoping someone was able to help me figure out what the issue is, as it's got me stumped. :(

Comment: This is way too much, please trim it down to an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You neither `flush()` nor `close()` the outputstream after writing an object to it, which means it's likely still on the server's memory, waiting for some more stuff to come along before sending it. TCP/IP has overhead; sending every byte one at a time is incredibly inefficient, hence why the notion of flushing exists.

Comment: I just changed the code to flush the outputstream after every write, but the issue still persists.